# Should mysql database be replicated in a replication setup

Tags: mysql, replication

When I do a replication setup I always ask myself should I put `mysql` and other internal databases (like `information_schema`) in the `binlog_ignore_db` option.

Documentation about replication I read never mention what to do with `mysql`, but I don't see any value (and rather see possible problem) to have these databases replicated.

The only benefits would be having all the users and permissions the same everywhere but I had a replication issue last week.
I created a user on both nodes of my setup using a configuration system, and the replication broke when the slave tried to replay the user creation coming from the logbin which was already existing so that's can be problematic.

What do you think?

Comment: information schema no as it is per instance information. The mysql schema depends on your setup. If you need to be able to 'fail over' to the replica then yes.

Comment: so what you say actually is it depends.
The root of my question is I had a replication issue last week because I created a user on both nodes, and the replication broke when the slave try to create the user which was already existing so that's can be problematic. I'll update my question with such information.

Comment: You should review how you create user or change objects, change them on the master only. Avoid any from of replication filtering/binlog filtering until you have a solid use case. Note filtering applies to default database and doesn't apply to database quantified queries like `insert into db.table`